# How to find occurrence of a string among string literals?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

While maintaining a large codebase, I came to a need to refactor the usage of a particular string constant (a single word).

I only need to refactor the string's usage among string literals; however the string also appears in other symbols such as class names and variables, therefore I would like to find all occurrences of the string only among string literals.

I use IntelliJ.

Does IntelliJ provide "search in string literals" feature?

If not, is there any other approach?

Comment: I'm sure you could paste some code into MSWord and modify the built in find & replace feature to only perform its actions on literals of your desired String.

Comment: That wouldnt help if his refactoring touches multiple files...

Comment: Oh, what about downloading Eclipse and using their built in refractor?

Comment: What about using `grep` with a regular expression that filters for string literals?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28720011/intellij-idea-search-in-java-strings/28720224#28720224

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Ctrl + Shift + F
```

Search in whole project.

Comment: Search with regular expression `".*foo.*"` will give you lines containing string literals...

Comment: Golden, thanks very much. "Search in string literals" is right there.

Comment: Hm, I don't see the _Search in string literals_ option, but when you hit enter, results are grouped, and one of the groups is called "Usage in string constants"

Answer (score 0):

Check the "In String Literals" option in File (CTRL + F) or Global (CTRL + Shift + F) Search - see [Intellij Idea : Search in java Strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28720011/intellij-idea-search-in-java-strings/28720224#28720224)