# Intellij Idea : Search in java Strings?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to search only in java strings in Intellij IDEA ?

I have searched and could not found anything on this. I have to refactor hibernate HQL queries written as java strings. If IDE support search in strings it will be lot more easy to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pressing CTRL + SHIFT + F gives you the possibility to search in "String literals only":

[image: CTRL + SHIFT + F]

This also works with CTRL + F:

[image: CTRL + F]

Additionally you can enable regular expression for some fancy searches.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am misunderstanding you, you could build a regular expression to search inside quotation marks: `"<whatever you need to search for>"`, something like so: `"from eg.Cat"`. If you want it slightly more generic, you could do: `"from .+?"`